# i am trying to write Euclidean Algorithm but program crash when i use loop in c code

Tags: c, algorithm, loops

I am trying to write the *Euclidean Algorithm* in C code. When I use the `do while` or `for` loop the program crashes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int gcd(int a,int b);

int main()
{
    int x,r,y;
    printf("Enter two values:\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    if(x<y)r=x,x=y,y=r;
    r=gcd(x,y);
    printf("\n\n   Result: %d",r);
    return 0;
}

int gcd(int a,int b)
{
    if(a==0||b==0)
    {
        if(a==0)return b;
        if(b==0)return a;
    }
    else
    {
        for(;;a>0||b>0)//also try with do while loop but problem same
        {
            int x;
            x=a%b;
            a=b;
            b=x;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please explain me the reason behind the crash of the program? I use codeblocks with `gcc`

Comment: you don't have an end condition in your for loop

Comment: Have **YOU** tried debugging? What were your findings?

Comment: .. and concerning the for-loop, there is no return after.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for(;;a>0||b>0)
```

is an infinite loop, then end condition is the middle part, it should be:

```
for (; a > 0 || b > 0;)
```

I doubt the logic of that condition, shouldn't it be `&&`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of
`if(x<y)r=x,x=y,y=r;` you will need to do:

```
if(x < y){
    r = x;
    x = y;
    y = r;
}
```

Also you will need to place condition in second statement of `for` loop. Instead of:

```
for(;;a>0||b>0)
{
    ...
}
```

you could do `while(a > 0 && b > 0)`.
Depending on your familiarity you could  use recursion like:

```
int hcf(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else
       return hcf(b, a%b);

}
```

Also note that your `hcf` function does not have return statement in `else` block. So you will have to use conditional return:

```
if (a == 0) return b;
else return a;
```

at the end of `hcf`function

Comment: The if statement with two comma operators is OK in that it is syntactically valid and does what’s required.  I agree it would be better rewritten as three statements. However, it isn’t necessary to swap the arguments; the algorithm will do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
for(;;a>0||b>0)
```

does nothing so you have an endless loop.

What seem to happen is that `b` becomes zero and then you do `a % 0` which is illegal and cause a crash.

Remember that it is the second statement in the for-loop that is the condition for terminating the loop - it's not the third. So maybe you wanted:

```
for( ; a>0||b>0; )
```